# Set focus on Extjs textfield

Tags: javascript, extjs

Currently I got problem with setting focus on extjs textfield. When form show, I want to set focus to First name text box and I try to use build in function focus() but still can't make it work.
I am happy to see your suggestion.

```
var simple = new Ext.FormPanel({

    labelWidth: 75, 
    url:'save-form.php',
    frame:true,
    title: 'Simple Form',
    bodyStyle:'padding:5px 5px 0',
    width: 350,
    defaults: {width: 230},
    defaultType: 'textfield',
    items: [{
            fieldLabel: 'First Name',
            name: 'first',
            id: 'first_name',
            allowBlank:false
        },{
            fieldLabel: 'Last Name',
            name: 'last'
        },{
            fieldLabel: 'Company',
            name: 'company'
        }, {
            fieldLabel: 'Email',
            name: 'email',
            vtype:'email'
        }, new Ext.form.TimeField({
            fieldLabel: 'Time',
            name: 'time',
            minValue: '8:00am',
            maxValue: '6:00pm'
        })
    ],

    buttons: [{
        text: 'Save'
    },{
        text: 'Cancel'
    }]
});

simple.render(document.body);
```

Comment: Where is the code which tries to set focus?

Comment: I couldn't get this to work, even with the delay in ExtJS 4.2 .. I imagine this needs to be done in some callback, but I can't find out which one.  I've tried the 'renderer' event listener on the view, and that did not work either.

Comment: See also [Set focus for text input in just created window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11092833/set-focus-for-text-input-in-just-created-window)

Answer (score 18):

Sometimes it helps to add a little delay when focusing. This is because certain browsers (Firefox 3.6 for sure) need a bit of extra time to render form elements.

Note that ExtJS's `focus()` method accepts `defer` as an argument, so try that:

```
Ext.getCmp('first_name').focus(false, 200);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it is not yet work. There may be another way to do it. Currently I am running it on browser FireFox 5.0.

Answer (score 13):

Based on [Pumbaa80's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6591823/2319844) and [Tanel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6592974/2319844) I have tried many things and found a way to do it. Here is the code:

```
{
    fieldLabel: 'First Name',
    name: 'first',
    id: 'first_name',
    allowBlank: false,
    listeners: {
      afterrender: function(field) {
        field.focus(false, 1000);
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: If we even keep the argument as `true` in `focus()`, it still works? Can you please explain this behavior..

Comment: If this solution works, please mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 8):

You should use "afterrender" event for your textfield if you want to set focus after form is rendered.

```
    {
        fieldLabel: 'First Name',
        name: 'first',
        id: 'first_name',
        allowBlank: false,
        listeners: {
          afterrender: function(field) {
            field.focus();
          }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Wrap simple.render(document.body) inside Ext.onReady, then you don't have to use delay

Comment: If you use the config - allowBlank: false, this may cause some validation issues in which case you need to set the false parameter and a slight delay wont hurt as well, eg field.focus(false, 1000)

Answer (score 5):

why not just add `defaultFocus : '#first_name'` instead of adding to much lines of code?

OR, after `this.callParent(arguments);` add this line `Ext.getCmp('comp_id').focus('', 10);`

Comment: The property defaultFocus appears to only be available for windows.  Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: ExtJs 6.6.0, defaultFocus doesn't work - I have a TabPanel -> FormPanel->textField.

Answer (score 4):

Try to add the following property:

```
hasfocus:true,
```

and use the function below:

```
Ext.getCmp('first_name').focus(false, 200);

{
    id: 'fist_name',
    xtype: 'textfield',
    hasfocus:true,
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I've been struggling with that issue today, and I think I got the solution. The trick is using the `focus()` method after the `show()` method was called on the Form Panel. That is, adding a listener to the `show` event:

```
Ext.define('My.form.panel', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    initComponent: function() {
        this.on({
            show: function(formPanel, options) {
                formPanel.down('selector-to-component').focus(true, 10);
            }
    });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I have also been struggling with getting the focus on a text box in the Internet Explorer(As the above suggestions are working fine in chrome and Firefox). Tried the solutions suggested above on this page but none of them worked in IE. After so many research I got the workaround that worked for me, I hope it will be helpful to others as well:

Use `focus(true)` or if you want to delay this then use `focus(true, 200)` simply.
In ref of the above problem the code would be:

```
  {
        fieldLabel: 'First Name',
        name: 'first',
        id: 'first_name',
        allowBlank: false,
        listeners: {
          afterrender: function(field) {
            field.focus(true);
          }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

That works for me. In textfield or textarea add listeners config:

```
listeners:{
            afterrender:'onRender'
        }
```

After, in your controller write function:

```
onRender:function(field){
    Ext.defer(()=>{
        field.focus(false,100);
    },1);
}
```

Ext.defer is wrap for *setTimout()*. Without *Ext.defer()* ***field.focus()*** doesn't work and i don't why.
You cant write that function in *listeners* config instead of using controller's function name, but good practice is hold functions in component's controller. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

My form was inside of a window and the textfield would not focus unless I focused the window first.

```
                listeners: {
                    afterrender: {
                        fn: function(component, eOpts){
                            Ext.defer(function() {
                                if (component.up('window')){
                                    component.up('window').focus();
                                }
                                component.focus(false, 100);
                            }, 30, this);
                        },
                        scope: me
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `afterlayout` event. Set a flag on the element to prevent focusing multiple times for stability.

```
afterlayout: function(form) {
  var defaultFocusCmp = form.down('[name=first]');
  if (!defaultFocusCmp.focused) {
    defaultFocusCmp.focus();
    defaultFocusCmp.focused = true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
UIManager.SetFocusTo = function (row, column) {
    var grd = Ext.getCmp('gridgrn');
    grd.editingPlugin.startEditByPosition({ 'column': column, 'row': row });

}
```

Comment: Please give some more details. What your code does? How it solves the ploblem?