# extjs4 - how to focus on a text field?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I can't seem to be able to focus a field in a form in extjs 4.

The doc lists a focus function for Text field (inherited from Component)  but it doesn't do anything in terms of focusing to the input field.

Here's a sample code from the docs

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    title: 'Contact Info',
    width: 300,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),        
    items: [{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        name: 'name',
        fieldLabel: 'Name',
        allowBlank: false 
    }, {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        id:'email',
        name: 'email',
        fieldLabel: 'Email Address',
        vtype: 'email'  
    }]
});
```

If I call `Ext.getCmp('email').focus()` nothing visible happens.

What's the correct way to focus a field in extjs 4?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set focus on Extjs textfield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6591371/set-focus-on-extjs-textfield)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't anything wrong with your code. I've made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GLctE/1/) for it and it works fine. Are you wrapping code in and `Ext.onReady()`? Also what browser are you using?

Comment: on FF 6.0.2 mac. Definitely wrapped in onReady handler.. your jsfiddle works for me.. must be something somewhere else in my code that must be stealing focus.. I guess i can try trimming out the rest of the code to where it starts working again. At least i know focus _should_ work now, thanks

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes a simple workaround is to slightly defer the focus call in case it's a timing issue with other code or even with the UI thread allowing the focus to take place.  E.g.:

```
Ext.defer(function(){
    Ext.getCmp('email').focus();
}, 0);
```

Comment: I would think that the defer option in the focus method would allow you to do this properly, but that does not seem to be the case. Thanks for the tip. +1

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Ext.getCmp('email').focus(false, 20);
```

Comment: To improve the quality of your post, please include why/how your answer solves the problem.

Comment: [This answer provides an explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6591823/1062992)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than work around with a delay, look for what is getting focus instead. Look out for focusOnToFront property on the parent.