# Set focus for text input in just created window

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I have trivial window:

```
   this.window = Ext.widget('window', {
            title: 'Find',
            closeAction: 'hide',
            width: 300,
            layout: 'fit',
            items: form
        });
```

with trivial form in it

```
var form = Ext.widget('form', {
    layout: {
        type: 'vbox',
        align: 'stretch'
    },
    border: false,
    bodyPadding: 10,

    items: [
        this.findInput,
    ]
});
```

which only has one item

```
    this.findInput = Ext.widget('textfield', {
        name: 'find'
    });
```

The issue is: how to set focus right after window is shown? I tried to call `.focus()` method of `this.findInput` in almost every window event handler with no luck.

Seems like even `afterrender` is called synchronously before DOM has created all the elements completely.

What have I missed? What event should I bind to to have all the elements rendered and able to accept the focus?

PS: if I call the same `.focus()` after small interval like 10ms - I get it focused, but it's not a solution

Comment: See also [Set focus on Extjs textfield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6591371/set-focus-on-extjs-textfield)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out `activeItem` property - http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel-cfg-activeItem

or you can also use `defaultFocus`: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.window.Window-cfg-defaultFocus

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work with `vbox` layout. At least after adding `activeItem: 0` to both form and window - nothing's changed. And in extjs sources I only see it in `card` layout

Comment: Try this one: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.window.Window-cfg-defaultFocus

Comment: Yep, `defaultFocus` is what I was looking for. Put it as an answer please